# How to send client system's properties to server computer in java?

Tags: java, networking

I want to create a java application that sends client computer's complete system info to the server computer. In the below program I'm able to achieve the task but the message gets split when it encounters a blank space. I tried removing the split method but it doesn't work.

The client should send the info to the server in a well formatted line by line fashion.

P.S- I had referred to an Youtube video tutorial.

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyClient 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket;

        try {
        datagramSocket=new DatagramSocket();    //Creating Datagram socket
        String message=System.getProperties().toString();     //Creating message

        byte [] bytes=message.getBytes();       //Converting string message to byte format
        InetAddress host= InetAddress.getByName("localhost");       //Specifying server address
        int server_socket=6780;                 //Defining the socket tot be used

            //Sending
            DatagramPacket request= new DatagramPacket(bytes,bytes.length,host,server_socket);
            datagramSocket.send(request);

            //Receiving
            byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
            DatagramPacket reply= new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
            datagramSocket.receive(reply);

            //Printing the reply
            System.out.println("Client Received: "+new String(reply.getData()));

            //Closing the socket
            datagramSocket.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}

**Server.java**

import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


    public class MyServer
 {

        public static void main(String[] args)
 {
            DatagramSocket datagramSocket=null;

            try {
                datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(6780);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                int i=0;

                while (true) {
                    DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    datagramSocket.receive(request);

                    String [] arrayMsg= (new String(request.getData())).split(" ");
                    byte [] sendMessage=(arrayMsg[i]+"  Server Processed").getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket reply=new DatagramPacket(sendMessage,sendMessage.length,request.getAddress(),request.getPort());

                    datagramSocket.send(reply);
                    i++;


                }
            }

        catch (Exception e) {


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you could try to split on something else. make something that 'll guaranteed be a token, "<+>" for instance, chances of that ever occuring are quite minimal.

Comment: You need to move the receive outside the split loop.

Comment: Never Write catch (Exception e) {                   } Always handle exceptions poperbly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid spliting into multiple packets at each space, remove the loop that splits into packets when some space is encountered:

So replace:

```
while (true) {
  DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
  datagramSocket.receive(request);
  String [] arrayMsg= (new String(request.getData())).split(" ");
  byte [] sendMessage=(arrayMsg[i]+"  Server Processed").getBytes();
  DatagramPacket reply=new DatagramPacket(sendMessage,sendMessage.length,request.getAddress(),
    request.getPort());
  datagramSocket.send(reply);
  i++;
  }
}
```

by:

```
  DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
  datagramSocket.receive(request);
  byte [] sendMessage = (request.getData() + " Server Processed").getBytes();
  DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(sendMessage,
                         sendMessage.length, request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
  datagramSocket.send(reply);
```

**Another way would be to split at end of line.**

Do not forget that using UDP like this, you can have:

- out of order packets
- lost packets in cas of congestion